# Getting a list from URL with a regular expression django

Tags: python, django

I have the following view for filter Order objects based on a list of ids:

```
class GetOrdersByIDs(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self)
        ids = self.kwargs.get('ids')
        return Order.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

I want to receive a list of ids from URL like this: `myurl/ids/1,2,3,4`, but I think I have to use a regular expression like this  `\d+(,\d+)*$`, but I don't know how to get a list from this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `query_param` for this. sth like: `.../?id=1&id=2&id=3`.

Then when you use `request.GET.getlist('id')`, it will return you a list like `[1,2,3]`:

```py
...
def get_queryset(self):
    ids = self.request.GET.getlist('id')
    return Order.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```